# While saving product throws "Unable to save Stock Item" exception in magento 2.2.6

Tags: product, backend, magento2.2.6, stock, save

While saving product in backend,throws "Unable to save Stock Item".

I have tried after flushed the cache and reindexing but still exception throws.

I have reffered below link, but no luck

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Cannot-add-products-in-Magento-2-1-11-quot-Unable-to-save-Stock/td-p/108369

In exception log throws

> [2019-04-09 11:04:50] main.CRITICAL: Unable to save Stock Item
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0): Unable
>   to save Stock Item at
>   /var/www/html/vega/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php:183,
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`vega`.`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT
>   `CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_STOCK_ID_CATINV_STOCK_STOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`stock_id`) REFERENCES `cataloginventory_stock` (`stock_id`) ON
>   DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_item`
>   (`product_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `min_qty`, `use_config_min_qty`,
>   `is_qty_decimal`, `backorders`, `use_config_backorders`,
>   `min_sale_qty`, `use_config_min_sale_qty`, `max_sale_qty`,
>   `use_config_max_sale_qty`, `is_in_stock`, `low_stock_date`,
>   `notify_stock_qty`, `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `manage_stock`,
>   `use_config_manage_stock`, `stock_status_changed_auto`,
>   `use_config_qty_increments`, `qty_increments`,
>   `use_config_enable_qty_inc`, `enable_qty_increments`,
>   `is_decimal_divided`, `website_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at
>   /var/www/html/vega/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235,
>   PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`vega`.`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT
>   `CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_STOCK_ID_CATINV_STOCK_STOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`stock_id`) REFERENCES `cataloginventory_stock` (`stock_id`) ON
>   DELETE CASCADE) at
>   /var/www/html/vega/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"}
>   []

Comment: You imported product via csv?

Comment: yes, I imported via csv

Comment: I have truncated the tables which is menioned in the above link, afer that i have tried to import products via csv. Now products are saved without quanity

Comment: product have custom options?

Comment: Have you tried reindex command?

Comment: I have tried reindex but no luck

Comment: @AmitNaraniwal, My csv does not contain custom oprions

Comment: @Jaisa, Can you post the error log here? If you getting any error in log file.

Comment: @AmitNaraniwal, I have posted my exception log file

Comment: If its not live website then go to this file `vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php` and remove the try catch section from save function so will get the idea what error you having.

Answer (score 2):

catalog_inventory_stock have filled default data when installing magento.
(ref : module-catalog-inventory/Setup/Patch/Data/CreateDefaultStock.php)
And the script truncate cataloginventory_stock.
So you need to fill default data manually like as below.

"INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock` (`stock_id`, `website_id`, `stock_name`) VALUES (1, 0, 'Default');"

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you for that answer!